# How can I compare array length in $match stage?

Tags: mongodb

`funding_rounds` below is an array, I'm trying to do the following query and get an error `$size needs a number`, what is the correct way to use `$size` with `$gte` in aggregation?

```
db.companies.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            $and: [
                {"founded_year": 2004}, 
                {"funding_rounds": {$size: {$gte: 5}}}
            ]
        }
    }
])
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**$size** operator should be used inside projections, so you need to transform your document before matching:

```
db.companies.aggregate([
    {
        "$project": {
            "_id": 1,
            "founded_year": 1,
            "funding_rounds": 1,
            "funding_rounds_size": { "$size": "$funding_rounds" }
        }
    },
    {
        "$match": {
            "$and": [
                {"founded_year": 2004}, 
                {"funding_rounds_size": { "$gte": 5 }}
            ]
        }
    }
])
```

There's also much shorter way to compare array length: you can check if fifth element exists:

```
db.companies.find(
    {
        "founded_year": 2004,
        "funding_rounds.4": { $exists: true }
    }
)
```